# How to fetch a value from the last element inside MySQL JSON document?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, greatest-n-per-group

I am using Mysql version `8.0.18-commercial`

My MySQL query is returning `JSON Document` for one of the column values.

```
ServerName      Status
abc.com         JSON Document(as shown below)
```

The `Status` column is similar to as below:

```
{
  "STEP1": {
    "state": "STARTED",
    "startTime": "2020-08-05T04:40:45.021Z"
  },
  ....
  ....
  "STEP4": {
    "state": "ENDED",
    "startTime": "2020-08-05T05:08:36.286Z"
  }
}
```

Desired Output:

```
ServerName      Status
abc.com         ENDED
```

I want to find the last `STEP` in my `JSON Document` and then  get the `state` value for it.

I have written the following query but it is not displaying last `state` value:

```
SELECT ServerName,
  (SELECT j.state
   FROM table t1
   CROSS JOIN json_table(Status, '$[*]' columns (state varchar(1000) PATH '$.state', startTime varchar(100) PATH '$.startTime')) j
   WHERE t1.id = t.id
   ORDER BY row_number() OVER (
                               ORDER BY j.startTime) DESC
   LIMIT 1) AS Status
FROM table AS t
```

Comment: Your query is wrong - window function cannot be used in this context. But the idea is correct. Parse the document by separate step objects in CTE. For each document - get the step object with greatest starttime in another CTE. Extract and return its state in main query.

Comment: Not sure how to parse step objects. Will it be possible to provide the updated query? Thanks!

Comment: *Not sure how to parse step objects.* You do this already using JSON_TABLE(). But you jump too deep - parse one level per CTE.

Comment: I have tried to do `json_table(Status, '$[0]' columns (state varchar(1000) PATH '$.state', startTime varchar(100) PATH '$.startTime')) j`  but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_table()` does not do what you think here: it is meant to operate on a JSON *array*, while your column contains a JSON *object*.

An alternative approach is to use `json_table()` with `json_keys()` to extract the object keys as rows: you can then extract the corresponding values, rank rows having the same `servername`, and keep the top row per group only:

```
select servername, state, starttime
from (
    select 
        t.servername,
        json_unquote(json_extract(t.status, concat('$.', j.k, '.startTime'))) starttime,
        json_unquote(json_extract(t.status, concat('$.', j.k, '.state'))) state,
        row_number() over(
            partition by t.servername 
            order by json_unquote(json_extract(t.status, concat('$.', j.k, '.startTime'))) desc
        ) rn
    from mytable t
    cross join json_table(
        json_keys(t.status), 
        '$[*]' columns (k varchar(50) path '$')
    ) j
) t
where rn = 1
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b080d2a409e5fbfa7647ec074650ffd0)**:

```
servername | state | starttime               
:--------- | :---- | :-----------------------
abc.com    | ENDED | 2020-08-05T05:08:36.286Z
```

Comment: thanks for the insights but as per the requirement it needs to be a sub-query. Is there a way to change it to a sub-query?

Comment: @meallhour: if you look closely, there is a subquery here.